# itunes JSON request in iOS returns an XML object

Tags: ios, xml, json, itunes-sdk

I want to access information from iTunes within an iOS app.

I am doing the regular http request (sending the parameters both as POST or directly in the URL)

The URL works, because if I use the browser, I get the expected result (in JSON format).

{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}

But within iOS, the JSONObjectWithData returns a null object.

After inspecting the data object, I found that the object returned is an XML object (that does not contain the required info, but instead a bunch of XML keys/values]

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/search"]];

NSError *directError;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&directError];

if (!directError) {
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonDict);

} else {
    NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", directError.localizedDescription);        
}
```

I looked into any possible POST parameter to force the response to be JSON, but didn't find anything.

Attached is a sample of the info contained in the data object (after XML parsing):

menus

key title

key Music

string url

key https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGenre?id=34

string items

key title

key Free on iTunes

string url

Regards... enrique

Comment: Can you show what URL are you checking?
Itunes API returns json as you can see here:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson

Comment: The test URL is https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=pink-floyd

Comment: I used http://itunes.apple.com/search in the question, to highlight the short JSON response     {
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}.     I tried http and https

Comment: I'm checking it and it works with that URL. If you want to check the data you have gotten, for example:
jsonDict[@"results"][0][@"trackName"]

Comment: I would guess that you're not explicitly asking for JSON, and many sites will return XML if you don't ask for JSON.  (I forget exactly how you "ask" for JSON, though.)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** I would also encourage you to not use the NSData dataWithURL method for fetching the contents since it triggers the request in synchronous manner. If you are requesting a lot of data then this will freeze the UI thread. For fetching you should almost always use asynchronous operations.

I am using the following code and it returns the JSON response which is later converted into the json object as shown below:

```
-(void) setup
{
    NSString *iTunesURL = @"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=pink-floyd";

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesURL] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

        NSLog(@"SUCCESS");

    }] resume];
}
```

Comment: Hi @azamsharp...   I did as you suggest (Launch the NSURLSession with dataTaskWithURL, but for some strange reason, the returned data object (that can be inspected) is not JSON but XML formatted... When I pass the NSData object through the NSJSONSerialization class, the returning object is nil. If I run it through the NSXMLParser, it gets a long list of keys, as shown in the attachment to the original question.  I am puzzled here. Any help will be appreciated... A sample protect with the issue is posted [here](https://github.com/eharo2/iTunes)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will cause the response to be in JSON instead of XML:

```
NSUrlSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{ @"Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" };

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/search"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

}] resume];
```

That's using the default headers from Chrome. You could also try this:

```
sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{ @"Accept" : @"text/json" };
```

And if that doesn't work:

```
sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{ @"Accept" : @"text/json, application/json" };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this issue and while the data being returned looks like XML, after analyzing the HTTP traffic, Apple is returning a redirect url that attempts to open iTunes on the device. By changing the user agent of NSMutableURLRequest, I was able to have JSON returned.

```
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=wwg&country=us&media=software")!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET";
    //Be seen as the Mac OS
    request.addValue("Paw/2.3.3 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.4) GCDHTTPRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    //OR if you want to be seen as Chrome
    //request.addValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        self.delegate?.didFinishSearching(data, response: response, error: error);
    }
    task.resume();
```